# Firebase Console Dynamic Link OFL Parameter

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-console

I need a dynamic link (short url) that:

on mobile:

- when app is installed -> open app
- when app is not installed -> open store

on desktop:

- open specific web url

I managed to get it working for the mobile part. However, on desktop it also opens the deeplink for the app. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) states to use the OFL parameter for that. Now if I manually add this parameter to the long url everything works as expected but I need a short url. How can I add this parameter via Firebase Console directly?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'ofl' feature is not yet available for Dynamic Links created via the Firebase console. Currently, this is only possible with [Manual URL construction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually#parameters) dynamic link. The idea is to add the "ofl" parameter to the url to make the FDL redirect another URL on the desktop, like displaying a full web page of the app content.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and i fixed it by using the property **longDynamicLink** that the **DynamicLinkParameters** object provides as they said in documentation:

```
/// Set the long Dynamic Link when building a short link (i.e. using `buildShortLink()` API). This allows the user to append
  /// additional query strings that would otherwise not be possible (e.g. "ofl" parameter). This will not work if using buildLink() API.
  final Uri? longDynamicLink;
```